# Keras np_utils.to_categorical behaves differently

Tags: python, keras

Why does Keras to_categorical behaves differently on [1, -1] and [2, -2]?

```
y = [1, -1, -1]
y_ = np_utils.to_categorical(y)
array([[ 0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.]])


y = [2, -2, -2]
y_ = np_utils.to_categorical(y)
array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.]])
```

Comment: Why would it behave the same way?

Comment: I suppose to_categorical shall convert y dataset to one-hot-vector dataset. [1] and [-1] shall have different encoded value. Just like [2] ==> [0,0,1] and [-2] ===> [0, 1, 0].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`to_categorical` does not take negative values, if you have a dataset that has negative values, you can pass `y - y.min()` to `to_categorical` so it works as you would expect:

```
>>> y = numpy.array([2, -2, -2])
>>> to_categorical(y)
array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.]])
>>> to_categorical(y - y.min())
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
y = np.array(y, dtype='int').ravel()
if not num_classes:
    num_classes = np.max(y) + 1
n = y.shape[0]
categorical = np.zeros((n, num_classes))
categorical[np.arange(n), y] = 1
```

above is the implementation of to_categorical.

So in [1, -1, -1] case what happened is :
num_classes = 2 [np.max()+1]
categorical shape becomes [3,2]
so when -1 comes it reads the last index and makes it 1. and for 1 also it reads index 1(index starts from 0).
that is why final output becomes

```
array([[ 0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.]])
```

in [2, -2, -2] case what happened is :
num_classes = 3 [np.max()+1]
categorical shape becomes [3,3]
so when -2 comes it reads the second last index and makes it 1. and for 2 it reads index 2(index starts from 0).
that is why final output becomes

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.]])
```

so if you try something like [2, -4, -4] it will give you an error as there is no index -4 as categorical shape is [3,3].